# How to run bootstrap theme related script files in Angular 4 project

Tags: jquery, angular

We are developing an Angular 4 project, and the design team has provided a bootstrap theme which has javascript codes to run the theme properly. On jquery document's ready function, there is a whole lot of code written, which when written inside Angular components onInit() doesn't work.

The following is a snippet of code in document ready function.

```
var Site = window.Site;
Site.run()
```

When I tried

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    var Site = window.Site;
    Site.run();
}
```

The browser's window object is undefined, so I wrote a service to get the window object, but still, this doesn't work.

How do I ensure that theme specific jquery code runs without affecting the angular components?

EDIT:
As mentioned by pelvice in the comment, I referenced the third party files in the angular-cli.json file. Now the issue is with not able to find '$'

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

I added jquery to node modules and imported that in the component, but still I am getting uncaught reference error for $ in the library js file.

Comment: I also have an Angular 4 + Bootstrap 4 in my project. I can get the window object without a service. However, did you include your jquery-theme file in .angular-cli.json file (scripts array)? Your problem might be more complex so it would be nice to see a code snippet.

Comment: @plvice My theme files contain a couple of javascript files which are immediately invocable. Do I need to include those in angular-cli.json ?